# Сделать "плавность" в js

Tags: javascript, html

Такой вопрос, есть ссылка, кликая на неё снизу открывается новый блок (hidden_content), но открывается "резко", как можно установить плавность открытия?

```
<script>
function toggle(el) {
el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none') ? '' : 'none'
}
</script>


<a onclick="toggle(hidden_content)"><h1 class="hidden">Ссылка</h1></a>
<div id="hidden_content" style="display: none;">
контент (открывающийся блок)
</div>
```

Comment: Это делается при помощи таймеров https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеку jquery, если вы новичок и не хотите быдлокодить. Там как раз есть метод .**toggle(200)**; где аргумент - время анимации в мс, есть так же методы .**slideToggle()** и .**toggleClass(".hidden")**, в последнем случае легко написать свою анимацию:

```
.element-to-toggle{
    display:block;
    transition:display, 0.3s, ease-in;
}
.element-to-toggle.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let toggle =  function (el, time) {
     el = document.getElementById(el);
     if(el.style.display !== 'none'){
     el.style.opacity = 1;
     let setFade = function(){
     el.style.transitionDuration =time+'s';
     el.style.opacity:0;
     let dropIt = function(){
       el.style='display:none;'; 
     }
     setTimeOut(dropIt, time+'000');
     };
     setTimeout(setFade,1);
  }

}
```

и обратно по аналогии;

но если ты действительно хочешь реализовать не с помощью #быдлокод
то воспользуйся css и простым скрипотом для toogle"

```
    let toogleClass = function(el, fromclass, toclass){
    el = document.getElementById(el);
    cC = el.getAttribute('class');
    if(cC === toclass) el.classname = fromclass;
    else if(cC === fromclass)el.classname = toclass;

};
```